# Editing elements geometry (trimming joined elements)

Tags: revit-api

I am exporting some data to Revit via API. The problem is that the result when having more than two elements meet at the same point is incorrect.

I have tried to edit the faces or the edges of the elements but it seems that they are read only and cannot be edited.

How to pass the correct geometry (faces & edges) to revit elements?

[image: Truss members in revit]

Answer (score 0):

What sort of elements are you trying to edit?  From the image it looks you're dealing with beams or some type of structural element.

Revit automatically joins two beams that are close to each other.  It assumes that you want to join, and will automatically change the geometry based on the material of the beam (concrete, steel, wood).  It's trying to be helpful, but it's not always desirable behavior.  The way that you override this behavior with the UI is by right clicking on the end of the beams and telling them not to join other beams. Then Revit will automatically adjust the geometry depending on how you set that property.

Assuming you're using beams, it's a hard to find, but there is a utility that allows you to do this through the API.  You can do this:

```
foreach (FamilyInstance beam in beams)
{
    // you'll need to disallow joining for both ends of the beam 
    StructuralFramingUtils.DisallowJoinAtEnd(beam, 0)
    StructuralFramingUtils.DisallowJoinAtEnd(beam, 1)
}
```

There might be other utilites if you're using a different type of family, but the process somewhat similar.

Comment: Yes, they are beams and I am actually trying to join the three beams together. I want to join any beams that meet at the same point. As you said, Revit joins two beams only, not the three beams as I prefer. Is there a method to enable this or to override their geometry?

Comment: if the user interface supports it, the API should as well. can you achieve what you want manually?

Comment: I haven't worked much with beams, but joining them in Revit can be tricky.  Since beams are usually connected to columns or the side of other beams, it assumes you aren't joining too many together at once.  The order you join them can make a difference in how it appears too.  Beams are special, and Revit makes a lot of assumptions about how you want to join beams.  It might be easier to model those as adaptive component families, and then use a different join command that is more straightforward.  You could try JoinGeometryUtils.JoinGeometry(doc, beam1, beam2) for that.

Comment: I found out that I can only adjust the trimming of the members only by coping each one with other close members.